# How to execute Java code from Batch script?

Tags: java, batch-file

I have to execute a java code using batch script where java code has to take a variable value generated from the .bat file and execute java code and then return the another variable value back to .bat .

In say, exec.bat file i l get a value "456" .this "456" has to be sent to java file and there after execution we get another value "789" .And I want this "789" to be return back to exe.bat .

Please let me know the code and syntax to be written in both java and batch file.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can pass the value as a command line parameter to your java program.

Comment: @Vikdor Please let me know the syntax to do so..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

**In Java code :**

At the end of the program put this line

```
System.exit(789);
```

Here `789` is the value you would return to your  batch file.

**In the batch file:**

```
@echo off
java Test %1
set exitcode=%ERRORLEVEL%
echo %exitcode%
```

Here

`java Test %1` is the usual java execution with argument passed from batch file where %1 will map to the first parameter passed to the batch file from command prompt (*like wise you could have %2 etc* ... [Check this article](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/server-management/how-do-i-pass-parameters-to-a-batch-file-) ).

`ERRORLEVEL` is the standard batch variable use to store the value returned from java

Assuming that your batch file name is `Test.bat`, you run this from command prompt batch as

`Test 456`

**EDIT**:Example for adding two numbers

Example.java

```
public class Example extends TestBase<String>
{
     public static void  main(String[] arg){
         int result = Integer.parseInt(arg[0].trim()) ;+Integer.parseInt(arg[1].trim())
          System.exit(result);
     }

}
```

Compile this file and generate a class file Example.class

Batch file :

Example.bat

```
@echo off
java Example %1 %2
set exitcode=%ERRORLEVEL%
echo %exitcode%
```

Put this batch file and Example.class in a folder. Open command prompt from that folder and run as follows

```
Example 111 222
```

This will print the addition of these two numbers